# What does Error 3112 indicate when compacting an MDB file?

Tags: ms-access, jet

What does Error 3112 indicate when compacting an MDB file?

The Error description is "Records can't be read; no read permission on 'xyz123.mdb'"

There is a known issue with the Compact function on some versions of Access MDBs.  Is the solution in this case to run the Microsoft utility JETCOMP.EXE on this file?

What are the other possible causes of this error?

Answer (score 1):

This could well be a sign of corruption, I would suggest that you treat it like that for now and try doing a compact/repair and also a decompile and see if that snaps it out of it.

This is of course assuming that you do have permissions on the database, you might also want to check which workgroup file you are “joined” to at the moment in case the above does not work

Answer (score 0):

I can't say the error pertains to any one issue I can think of. It possbile that some other routine or part of the applicaton is open and not closed.

I assume this error is occurring for only one application ?

Try creating a blank database file, and then import everything into that file. Does the compact and repair now work? This sounds more like a damaged or currupted file.

Comment: The issue is about compaction of an MDB file. This is when the error occurs.

Comment: Understood, but to start suggesting using jetcomp is a red herring until we determine under what circumstances this problem is occurring under. If this is a damaged or corrupted file then the error message is rubbish and we can't determine anything of ANY use from that message except that you have a damaged file.  By importing the data into a fresh created mdb file and if this results in the error going away when you do a C + R tells us you had a damaged file. (asking about jetcomp or what color the sky is will not yield any useful info if that copy fixes this problem)

Comment: Albert's website is here: http://www.google.com/search?q=albert+d.+kallal . That is, Albert is a very active poster in a number of forums, so you'll find lots of his work in many places.